# irreducible module has a nonzero weight space if and only if $u\left( H\right) \cdot v$ is finite dimensional for all $v\in V$

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

**Question**:

Throughout this question, $L$ will denote a semisimple Lie algebra(over the algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic 0), $H$ a fixed CSA of $L$, $u(H)$ universal enveloping algebra of $H$.

Let $V$ be an irreducible $L-$module.Then $V$ has a (nonzero) weight space if and only if $u\left( H\right)  \cdot v$ is finite-dimensional for all $v\in V$.

This question comes from J.E. Humphreys's book *Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory*. Exercises p111 2.(b)

**Attempt**:

$\Rightarrow $ Since irreducible and  $V$ has a (nonzero) weight space, so $V$ is the direct sum of its weight space $V=\sum V_{\lambda }$. For $v\in V$, $v=\sum^{s}_{i=1} v_{i}$,$v_{i}\neq 0 $, then we have
$$h\cdot v=h\cdot \sum v_{i}=\sum \lambda_{i} \left( h\right)  v_{i}\in <v_{1},...,v_{s}>$$
for all $h\in u\left( H\right)$,so $u\left( H\right)  \cdot v$ is finite-dimensional.

**Can we prove** $u\left( H\right)  \cdot v=<v_{1},...,v_{s}>$?

$\Leftarrow$ I don't have a good idea.

Comment: This is missing some explanation of your notation. What is $H$? What is $u$?

Comment: @Callum I add to the source of the problem.

Comment: One could then add: $L$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, $H$ a Cartan subalgebra etc

Comment: I add the meaning of the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Leftarrow$ Denote the representation by $\pi$.  Let $v\in V$, $v\ne 0$.  Let $W=\pi(u(H))v$.  Then by assumption $W$ is finite dimensional.  Since $H\cdot u(H)\subseteq u(H)$ then $$\pi(H)(W)=\pi(H)\pi(u(H))v=\pi(H\cdot u(H))v\subseteq\pi(u(H))v=W$$

Since $H$ is Abelian, so is $\pi(H)\rvert_W\subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(W)$.  An Abelian Lie algebra is solvable.  By Lie's Theorem (Section 4.1 in the book), $W$ contains a common eigenvector $w\in W$, $w\ne 0$ of $\pi(H)\rvert_W$ and then $\operatorname{span}(\{w\})$ is a non-zero weight space.

Notes:

- $\pi:u(L)\to\operatorname{End}_F(V)$ is a homomorphism of associative algebras.  $u(H)$ is an associative subalgebra of $u(L)$.  $H$ is a Lie subalgebra of $u(H)$ whose bracket derived from the associative multiplication in $u(H)$ coincides with its *intrinsic* Lie bracket.  $\pi$, as an associative homomorphism, is also a Lie homomorphism on the Lie bracket derived from the associative multiplication.
- The weight space $\operatorname{span}(\{w\})$ is non-zero, but the associated weight *may* be zero.  This is not a problem as other weight spaces are derived as in section 20.1 of the book.

Comment: I think you're confusing the representation of a lie algebra with the representation of an associative algebra. By treating $H$ as an associative algebra, you prove that $W$ is the representation space of $H$, but Lie's Theorem holds only for the representation of lie algebras

Comment: @zeyuhao:  I'm not confusing.  The notation may be confusing.  See edit.

Comment: I think $\pi (H)\left( W\right)  =\pi \left( H\right)  \pi \left( u\left( H\right)  \right)  v=\pi \left( \left[ H,u\left( H\right)  \right]  \right)  v-\pi \left( u\left( H\right)  \right)  \pi \left( H\right)  v$

Comment: @zeyuhao:  No, $\pi$ is multiplicative on $u(H)$.  For $h_1, h_2\in H$, $\pi(h_1 \cdot h_2)=\pi(h_1)\pi(h_2)$ and $\pi([h_1,h_2]_i) = \pi(h_1\cdot h_2-h_2\cdot h_1) = \pi(h_1)\pi(h_2)-\pi(h_2)\pi(h_1)$, where $[,]_i$ is the intrinsic bracket of $H$.  It's because $[h_1,h_2]_i=h_1\cdot h_2-h_2\cdot h_1$ in $u(H)$.

Comment: I‘m very sorry, I just noticed your edit. You're right, I was wrong to think $\pi :L\rightarrow gl\left( V\right)  $. Thank you again for your patience.